# multiprocessing.Queue may lose element inside it

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I use `multiprocessing.Queue` to deal with ad creation. But it seems some elements got lost when using Queue.get() (for example, I put 10 ads in the Queue, but only 8 were processed after multiprocessing work finished).

The code is:

```
from multiProcessing import Process, Queue, JoinableQueue

def create_ad(origin_queue, ad_queue):
    ''' ad creation'''
    for ad in iter(origin_queue.get, None):
        try:
            # do sth else

            ad_queue.put(ad)
        except:
            pass
            # actually there exists logging here, no error outside
        finally:
            origin_queue.task_done()
    origin_queue.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':

     origin_queue = JoinableQueue()
     # mock to put ads inside
     ads = [1,2,3,4,5]         
     [ origin_queue.put(ad) for ad in ads ]

     ad_queue = Queue()
     process_list = []
     for p in range(4): # PROCESS_NUM
         process = Process(target=create_ad, args=(origin_queue, ad_queue))
         process_list.append(process)
     for process in process_list:
         process.daemon = True
         process.start()

     origin_queue.join()

     for process in process_list:
         origin_queue.put(None)
     origin_queue.join()

     while not ad_queue.empty():
         ad = ad_queue.get()   # number of ad got here is different from ads put inside it
```

Is my Queue's usage wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you are hiding errors that happen when you do this:

```
   try:
        ad_queue.put(ad)
    except:
        pass
```

try removing the `except`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but why it's related with exception part? As my understanding, as finally code will always be executed, it should be no related with exception~  Actually, I use logger.exception(e) in real code, but no exception logged

Answer (score 0):

add block for your queue, or it will raise exception, you have discarded,  when full or empty.

Comment: thanks, you mean the "while not ad_queue.empty()" part ?

Comment: from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue), multiprocessing.Queue uses producer-consumer pattern, it should use lock inside it already

Answer (score 0):

Try `Manager().Queue()` or just `SimpleQueue()` instead of `Queue()`.